# Share TCP Connection between threads with tokio rust (Multiplexor)

Tags: rust, tcp, rust-tokio

I would like to know if there is a way to share the same tcp connection between different threads without the need to block it.

The problem that appears is that if you have different threads sharing the same connection with a `clone()` at the moment that one of these threads is blocked writing or reading, another thread would not be able to interact with this TCP connection because it is blocked. Is there any way to avoid this without the need to create a connection for each thread? In a server with few threads it can work, but when we try to scale we don't want to have as many connections as threads.

For example in rabbitMQ you can share the same tcp connection through different channels, so the different threads can communicate with that tcp connection to the server because they have an independent channel over that tcp connection.

Is there any function or attribute of Tokio that allows this? Is there any other library to be able to share TCP connection from independent channels on this one to avoid blocking?

Comment: Doo you want to share a [TcpListener](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html), or [TcpStream](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html)?

Comment: Sharing without some kind of synchronization is a recipe for unintentionally interleaved writes.

Comment: TCP connections are ultimately serial - data written is delivered in the written order - and this is basically one of the underlying guarantees of TCP so there's no way to escape it. Protocols which let you "share" a TCP connection are doing their own multiplexing on top of TCP. ...

Comment: ... one simple method to do this is to have one thread reading data from a multi-producer queue and writing that data to a TCP connection. This is simple enough, however there is no obvious choice as to how to reconstruct different parallel "messages" on the receiving end, only by knowing the characteristics of the data you are sending (which you haven't described) can you come up with a scheme to do so. One such scheme, for example, is tagging each portion of each message, then putting the messages in a map from Tag to Message on the receiving end.